# How to apply color to barchar in react-bar-chart

Tags: reactjs

I have installed `react-bar-chart` using

```
npm i react-bar-chart --save
```

And I was using below code to display the bar chart, I can see the bar chart rendering on UI, but color is defaulted to black, I tried adding `style={{color: 'blue'}}`, but it's not working.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import BarChart from "react-bar-chart";

class Metrics extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      { text: "DOB", value: 500 },
      { text: "Address", value: 300 },
      { text: "Email", value: 900 },
      { text: "Phone", value: 100 },
      { text: "Name", value: 700 }
    ];

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
          <BarChart
            ylabel="Quantity"
            width={500}
            height={500}
            margin={margin}
            data={data}
            style={{ color: "blue" }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Metrics;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it renders as svg, you need to use fill property instead of color:

```
.bar { fill: blue; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, It is working. I have 2 questions here
1. How did you figure out this is rendering as svg, 
2. How can i apply different colors to bars.

Comment: Just dig into their examples on github: https://github.com/MateusZitelli/react-bar-chart/blob/master/example/BarChart.css